# MVC submit multiple objects in model when form post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I am facing a problem that when I have a complex Model, if I submit the form it will not give me all the values of all the model properties, in the below example, I am not getting back the gridModel properties:

**Model**

```
public class InventoryModel {
    public GridModel GridModel { get; set; }
    public Int32 UserKey { get; set; }
}

public class GridModel {
    public String GridId { get; set; }
    public String GridName { get; set; }
    public List<String> columns { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    InventoryModel model = new InventoryModel();

    model.UserKey= 20014;
    model.GridModel = new GridModel();
    model.GridModel.GridId = "jqgInventory";
    model.GridModel.GridName = "Inventory Grid";
    return View(model);
}

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(InventoryModel model){
    Int32 userId = model.UserKey; // This has a value
    String gridId = model.GridModel.GridId;  // This doesn't have a value
    String gridName= model.GridModel.GridName; // This doesn't have a value
}
```

**View**

```
@model InventoryModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserKey, new { @class = "w200" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GridModel.GridId , new { @class = "w200" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GridModel.GridName, new { @class = "w200" })

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Any suggestion please would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Alaa

Comment: Look into creating a custom model binder.

Answer (score 3):

You could instead use a ViewModel rather than the actual Model. This would be a flatter class that reflects the data specifically for the View.

```
public class InventoryViewModel{
    Int32 UserKey {get; set; }
    public String GridId { get; set; }
    public String GridName { get; set; }        
}
```

Your controller can map your model to your ViewModel if necessary